# Prevent duplicate names in a DataGridView

Tags: c#

I am using this code to check and prevent duplicate names when I insert names in a database table. So if the name exists it will prevent the insert and a MessageBox will be displayed warning that the name exists. if not, a MessageBox is displayed confirming the operation is done.

```
string Coonstring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=****;Charset=utf8";

using (MySqlConnection connectionDatabase = new MySqlConnection(Coonstring))
{
    try
    {
        connectionDatabase.Open();
        using (MySqlCommand select = new MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM project.name_registry WHERE Name=@NM", connectionDatabase))
        {
            select.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NM", txt.Text);
            if (select.ExecuteScalar() != 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Name exists");
                return;
            }
        }
        using (MySqlCommand cmddata = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO project.name_registry (name) VALUES(@NM)", connectionDatabase))
        {
            cmddata.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NM", txt.Text);
            cmddata.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Done");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

My problem is when I run the code above, the following error is thrown

> > Specified cast is not valid.

What does this mean?

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: `select.ExecuteScalar() != 0` should throw a different compiler error since `ExecuteScalar` returns an `object` and not an `int`. You have to cast it to `int`

Answer (score 1):

```
if (select.ExecuteScalar() != 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Name exists");
    return;
}
```

use

```
if(int.Parse(select.ExecuteScalar()) !=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

use parse  or cast

```
if ((Int32)select.ExecuteScalar() != 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Name exists");
    return;
}
```

or

```
if(int.parse(select.ExecuteScalar().ToString())!=0)
{
MessageBox.Show("Name exists");
        return;
}
```

Comment: Use `parse`? Where do you use _parse_?

Answer (score 0):

Both with parse

```
if (int.Parse(select.ExecuteScalar()) != 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Name exists");
    return;
}
```

or casting

```
if (((int)select.ExecuteScalar()) != 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Name exists");
    return;
}
```

should work.

Comment: select.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NM", txt.Text);
                        if ((Int32)select.ExecuteScalar() != 0)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Name exists");
                            return;
                        }                                                                  I still face the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
var count = 0;
var obj = select.ExecuteScalar();
if(obj != null)
{
    count = Convert.ToInt32(obj);

    if(count != 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Name exists");
        return;
    }
}
else
{
    throw new Excepion();
}
```

Comment: I will check and give you feedback about the status.Kind Regards